# What does "prize" in "the prize Middle White boar" mean? Can It be used as an adjective?

Tags: meaning

I read "the prize Middle White boar" in George Orwell's *Animal Farm*.

I read it on my kindle book.

The full sentence is:

> Word had gone round during the day that old Major, the prize Middle White boar, had had a strange dream on the previous night and wished to communicate it to the other animals.

Click: http://www.marxists.org/subject/art/literature/children/texts/orwell/animal-farm/ch01.htm

What does "prize" mean here? What kind of pig is this?

Comment: Please add the full sentence to your question. *Prize* here has this definition: [2. Given a prize, or likely to win a prize: *a prize cow*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prize). It's a "middle white boar"; presumably that's some kind of pig, though I don't think any information beyond that is about English (but rather animals). I googled it anyway; [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_White) might help.

Comment: I've editted the question.

Comment: "a prize cow" or "a prized cow"?

Comment: As an adjective, *prize* simply means *[good enough to deserve or win a prize](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/prize_15)*, which you will find in any dictionary.

Comment: And to round it out, a [*boar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_pig#Glossary_of_terms) is an adult male pig, and [Middle White](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_White) is a particular pig breed (just like Golden Retriever is a dog breed).

Comment: @dennylv  The correct spelling is edited, not editted.

Comment: See prize, adjective, in Oald http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/prize_2 - A pity that they label it as adjective. Attribute, combining form, subelement of a compound noun would be better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an adjective, *prize* means “likely to win a prize”. This means that if the boar entered a contest, it would have a good chance of winning. It doesn't necessarily imply that the animal has ever entered a contest or ever will, just that it has the qualities that would make it a likely winner. This is mostly applied to animals (*prize cow*) and to plants (*prize orchid*), but can also be applied to other concepts (*prize essay*, *prize performance*, …).

*Prize-winning* would mean that the animal has won at least one prize.

*Prized* is rather different. A *prized* possession is something whose owner puts a high price on, i.e. something that the owner considers to be so valuable that he does not wish to part from it. It can either be objectively valuable, in the sense that it would fetch a high price if the owner sold it, or subjectively, in the sense that the owner does not want to part from it, perhaps for sentimental reasons. In the subjective sense, *treasured* is more often used than *prized*.

Comment: It may only mean that the animal has won a prize at some time in the past.